# Android: Read child node's key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, key

**Intro**:*I have created the database of my app as in the picture below.*

[image]

*In order to display user's saved books I am trying first to read user's books keys (located in `user-books` directory) and save all of those keys in an ArrayList so I can later load (from `books` directory) the BookObjects corresponding to those keys in a fragment called `MybooksFragment`.*

Note: *I am trying to get and  display those keys in a ListView as you can see below*: *(To be sure that I am getting the keys correctly)*

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_books, container, false);

    final ListView booksIdListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.booksIdListView);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference();

    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String UID = user.getUid();

    databaseReference.child("books").child(UID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            final List<String> booksId = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (DataSnapshot child:  dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String userBookId = child.getKey();

                booksId.add(userBookId);
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> myBooksAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity() ,
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , booksId);
            booksIdListView.setAdapter(myBooksAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

**Unfortunately the ListView remains empty (not populated with keys as I hoped).
What am I doing wrong?**

*Note: I am using this database model so I can dodge duplicate data*

Comment: Try using firebase listadapter to populate nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are "trying first to read user's books keys (located in user-books directory) and save all of those keys in an ArrayList" but you actually don't do it.

So in order to achieve this, you need to change your reference like this:

```
databaseReference.child("user-books").child(UID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

Because the node in which you want to query is `user-books` and not simple `books`.

To keep the code in same way as it is now, you need to make a little change in your database that sounds like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- user-books
          |
          --- userId1
          |     |
          |     --- bookId1: true
          |     |
          |     --- bookId2: true
          |     |
          |     --- bookId2: true
          |
          --- userId2
                |
                --- bookId4: true
                |
                --- bookId5: true
                |
                --- bookId6: true
```

You only need as childrens the unique book ids with the value of true.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It was a silly mistake to reference to child  "books". I copy pasted the eventListener from other fragment that was getting objects from "books" child and forgot to modify it here in "user-books". Now it works. Can't believe how silly I was. Could you please re-phrase why would I need to add values of true to the book ids?

Comment: To simplify your database. You don't need to use the `bookId` twice, once as a key and once as a value of `bookId`, you can simply use it only once. You will be able to get those childrens in the same way becase you have the key as the `book id` and the value of true.